# Grunt in sails.js failing to recognise new task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js

I am trying to add a new grunt task in a sails.js application.

To keep my test case simple i have copied the copy task to a new file copy-tests.js, which is also in the tasks/config folder.

I have modified copy-tests.js to update the first param of the set method to 'copy-tests', so it now reads

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('copy-tests', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './assets',
                src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less)'],
                dest: '.tmp/public'
            }]
        },
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: 'www'
            }]
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

I have updated compileAssets.js to add my new tasks, so it now reads

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'jst:dev',
        'less:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'copy-tests:dev',
        'coffee:dev',
        'jade:dev'
    ]);
};
```

When i try to lift the sails app i get 'Task "copy-tests:dev" not found'

I know that grunt can see my file as i have added a log statement to Gruntfile.js as follows

```
var taskConfigurations = loadTasks('./tasks/config'),
    registerDefinitions = loadTasks('./tasks/register');
    console.log(taskConfigurations);
```

I can see copy-tests in among the other tasks when this statement logs

Can anyone help with why grunt claims it can't find copy-tests:dev ?

Alternatively maybe i am going about this the wrong way. What i am trying to achieve is having two copy tasks, one to copy my main build content to the .tmp folder, and a second one to copy my client side tests to the .tmp folder. Later i will make sure that only my dev builds run both copy tasks, my prod one will only run the first one. I thought the best way to do this would be with two grunt tasks in the config folder, but maybe there is another way...

Comment: Did you also define `copy-tests` in the tasks/register folder?

Comment: it is compileAssets.js as described above, which is in the tasks/register folder. Was there somewhere else in the register folder you think it is needed ?

Comment: editing my question to make my intent clearer, as i don't want to define a new type of grunt task, just reuse an existing one

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're calling `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');` twice--once for your copy task, and once for your copy-tests task. Try removing the second one. Alternatively, try expanding the copy task and see if you can get that to work.

Comment: removing the second grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy'); made no difference. See my answer for final solution, thanks for the pointers Jonathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than define a second task to have an alternative copy, i needed to add to the Copy task as follows

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('copy', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './assets',
                src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less)'],
                dest: '.tmp/public'
            }]
        },
        devTests: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './tests',
                src: ['**/*.*'],
                dest: '.tmp/public/tests'
            }]
        },          
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: 'www'
            }]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

My compileAssets then looks like

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'jst:dev',
        'less:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'copy:devTests',
        'coffee:dev',
        'jade:dev'
    ]);
};
```

I realised this when i looked at the sails-linker.js task and saw how many targets there were in that. I had been thinking of the targets as build targets and assuming they would have values like dev, test, prod etc, but it appears that they are a broader concept and every type of copy i might want to do should be a target in the copy.js task.